# How can I send a file as an email attachment?

Tags: php, excel, spreadsheet

Spreadsheet WriteExce of John McNamara working ok to downloading the excel file.

currently use this function to export data from mysql and generate the excel. working properly to perform action download, but I would like to create action emailing. I have everything set up but I just need to change the action download to save to tmp, for example

But how I can generate the Excel tmp and send it by email?

```
    <?php
        include("include/conexion.php"); // CONECT TO BBDD
        require_once('include/write_excel/Worksheet.php'); // CLASS EXCEL
        require_once('include/write_excel/Workbook.php'); // CLASS EXCEL
        include_once("include/Classes/class.phpmailer.php"); // CLASS EMAIL

        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$filename" );

        $filename = "Listado.xls";

        // Creating a workbook
        $workbook = new Workbook("-");
        $worksheet1 =& $workbook->add_worksheet('Listado');

        $formato_texto_negrita =& $workbook->add_format();
        $formato_texto_negrita->set_bold(0x2BC);
        $formato_texto_negrita->set_align('left');
        $formato_texto_negrita->set_size(8);

        $formato_texto =& $workbook->add_format();
        $formato_texto->set_align('left');
        $formato_texto->set_size(8);

        $formatot2 =& $workbook->add_format();
        $formatot2->set_align('right');
        $formatot2->set_size(8);

        $formato_numero =& $workbook->add_format();
        $formato_numero->set_align('right');
        $formato_numero->set_num_format('0.000,00;[Red]-0.000,00');
        $formato_numero->set_size(8);

        $i=3;
        $j=0;
        $k=0;
        $opcionListado = $_POST['opcionListado'];

        $worksheet1->set_column($k,$k++,10); // CLAVE
        $worksheet1->set_column($k,$k++,10); // Recepcion
        $worksheet1->set_column($k,$k++,15); // Ubicacion
        // NAME OF COLUMNS…..

        $res = mysql_query($query, $conexion);

        for($l=0;$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);$l++)
        {
        // DATE ROWS…….
        }

        file_put_contents($filename, $workbook->close());
?>
```

and the email code include in other php.

Comment: I have edited the question title to make it clearer so people can better help you but it might be worth googling the question title now as I think there will be lots of info.

Comment: You should store the excel file in a temp folder and then attach the file to your mail ;)

Answer (score 0):

This article should help you:

http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/php-email-form-attachment.html

Failing that, I would suggest you just use [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=attach%20file%20to%20php%20using%20email&oq=attach%20file%20to%20php%20using%20email&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.5317&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) as this topic is covered multiple times already.

Comment: send_email.php what I have created and sent correctly, what I need is to create the excel in tmp folder and attach in the send_email.php

Comment: That is what this tutorial covers. Attaching a file to an email from an uploaded form.

Answer (score 0):

Just generate your Spreadsheet as normal to a tmp Directory. Then i would suggest you to use the php mail libary swift mail.

Take a look at this Example

http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#attaching-dynamic-content

Comment: "Just generate your Spreadsheet as usual to a tmp Directory." That's what I need, as I can do?